# VLOOKUP from another worksheet

Tags: excel, vlookup

Could someone please assist me with the following VLOOKUP query.

I have data in Column A on one spreadsheet and I need to match the data that is contained within this column, against Column A in another open spreadsheet and if they match populate Column B in the first spreadsheet with the data contained with Column B in the second spreadsheet.

Can anyone assist as I'm not sure of how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in cell B* in sheet2 (where * is the row number) `=vlookup(A*, 'Sheet1'!A:B, 2, FALSE)`